# What does "something goes weeeeeeeeee" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across a Rust programming library at https://github.com/image-rs/lzw. It states that

> LZW en- and decoding that goes weeeee!

What does "goes weeeee" mean? I guess it probably means very good, but I'm not sure and I can't find it in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whee is an exclamation used to express delight: https://www.google.com/search?q=whee+definition&oq=whee+def&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i20i263i512j0i512j0i10i22i30j0i22i30.3544j1j9&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

It is mostly commonly used by children on playground rides for example.

To go whee would be to use something that makes you exclaim in delight. E.g. the child went whee down the slide

Whee is commonly misspelled as wee. I believe the sentence is saying the library does encoding with the ease and fun of sliding down a slide

Answer (score 1):

"weeee" is the sound of something light, fast and fun.

It is childish language, that you might use when pushing a child on a swing, or commenting on a firework. It's use here is a joke, but it suggests a lightweight, fast software package (for lzw compression).  It might even be fun!